# Introduction to algebraic number theory

Tags: soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

How do you get started in algebraic number theory?

I am an undergraduate going through a Bachelor in Applied Computer Science and I just finished my first course in Algebra. My university (Göttingen) hosts many brilliant mathematicians, and I am lucky enough to get a chance at studying under Prof. Dr. Preda Mihailescu in his course of Algebraic Number Theory (ANT). This is happening in October. I wanted to get a feel of what he would cover and I downloaded some exercises from last year's course of ANT and I must say that I find them really difficult and much too abstract for my level. Thankfully I will have two months off in summer and have time to find a remedy.

Are there any good books to consult and study, before the start of the semester, to develop a decent understanding of the subject? I reiterate that my foundations are linear and geometric algebra.

Thank you for your time!
E. S. L.

Comment: Did you try asking Preda himself...?

Comment: No, actually, mostly because I haven't met him yet. I saw him hanging around the mathematical institute, but at that time I did not know I would attend one of his courses. Do you think I should ask him directly?

Comment: Of course! Why not? Chances are he's a nice guy.

Comment: Alright, I'll ask him next time I see him, cheers for the tip!